# How to groupby and sum while not counting duplicated values in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change time format from 12:45 to datetime format while keeping it in that form and calculate time difference for activities (results in activity_duration). Second of all I want to sum activity_duration grouped by activity_station

I changed time to datetime format but i get random year, month, day etc. I know how to groupby but not how to get rid of duplicates while applying groupby.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Shift_id' :[ 123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,
                345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345],
    'activity_id' : [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,
                    6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9],
    'activity_begin_time' : ['09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30','17:25','09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30','17:25','09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30','17:25',
                            '09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30','09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30','09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30','09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30'],
    'activity_end_time' : ['09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25','17:30','09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25','17:30','09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25','17:30',
                          '09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25','09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25','09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25','09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25'],
    'activity_station' : ['None', 'Za','None','Ba','None','None', 'Za','None','Ba','None','None', 'Za','None','Ba','None',
                         'None','Za','Ba','Ra','None','Za','Ba','Ra','None','Za','Ba','Ra','None','Za','Ba','Ra']
})


df['activity_begin_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['activity_begin_time'])
df['activity_end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['activity_end_time'])
df['activity_duration'] = df['activity_end_time'] - df['activity_begin_time']
df['activity_duration'] = df['activity_duration']/np.timedelta64(1,'h')
```

I want to sum the acitivity_duration grouped by activity_station while getting rid of duplicated values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Shift_id' :[ 123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,
                345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345,345],
    'activity_id' : [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,
                    6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9],
    'activity_begin_time' : ['09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30','17:25','09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30','17:25','09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30','17:25',
                            '09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30','09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30','09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30','09:00','09:05','12:00','12:30'],
    'activity_end_time' : ['09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25','17:30','09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25','17:30','09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25','17:30',
                          '09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25','09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25','09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25','09:05','12:00','12:30', '17:25'],
    'activity_station' : ['None', 'Za','None','Ba','None','None', 'Za','None','Ba','None','None', 'Za','None','Ba','None',
                         'None','Za','Ba','Ra','None','Za','Ba','Ra','None','Za','Ba','Ra','None','Za','Ba','Ra']
})
```

Drop duplicates frirst:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Use [pandas.to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['activity_begin_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['activity_begin_time']+':00')
df['activity_end_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['activity_end_time']+':00')
df['activity_duration'] = df['activity_end_time'] - df['activity_begin_time']
```

And then you can use specific aggregation per column with a [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html):

```
df.groupby('activity_station').agg({'activity_duration': np.sum})
```

Which produces:

```
                   activity_duration
activity_station    
Ba                 05:25:00
None               00:45:00
Ra                 04:55:00
Za                 05:50:00
```